# How to make the MOSS 2007 My Site profile fields not act as searchable links?

Tags: sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2007, profile, mysite

I have a MOSS 2007 instance where my client wants the content that comes in the My Site profile to not show up as links. How can we achieve this?

I tried removing the preferred search center url from the SSP. It did the trick but it also broke the standard search functionality that resides on the top right hand side of the page (below the welcome menu).

Answer (score 0):

Add a crawl rule which exclude content with http://server/MySites/* (change based on the location of your MySites) in the URL

This will only affect future crawls so you have to do a new full crawl or use Remove URLS from Search Result

Comment: I need the mysites to be included in the crawl but i want the fields that are displayed on the profile to displayed as plain text NOT search links.